# How to demonstrate the Generalization of Bayes' Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

### The theorem

> Let $(Ω,\mathscr{C},P)$ be a probability space. If the events
>   $A_1,A_2,...,A_n∈\mathscr{C}$ are incompatible two to two, with
>   $P(A_i)> 0, ∀i=1,2,...,n$ and such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{i=n}A_{i}=Ω$ ,
>   then, for any event $B∈C$, such that $P(B)>0$, it follows that:
>
> $$P(A_k|B)=\frac{P(B|A_k)\cdot P(A_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}P(B|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)}\quad\text{for all }k=1,2,...,n.$$

### My demonstration

**By definition of Conditional Probability:**

1. $\displaystyle P(A_k|B)=\frac{P(A_k∩B)}{P(B)}$
2. $\displaystyle P(B|A_k)=\frac{P(A_k∩B)}{P(A_k)}$
3. $\displaystyle P(A_k∩B)=P(B|A_k)\cdot P(A_k)$
4. $\displaystyle P(A_k|B)=\frac{P(B|A_k)\cdot P(A_k)}{P(B)}$

**By the Total Probability Theorem, concludes that:**

5. $\displaystyle P(B) = \sum_i P(B\cap A_i) = \sum_i P(B|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)$
6. $\displaystyle P(A_k|B)=\frac{P(B|A_k)\cdot P(A_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}P(B|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)}$

---

### *Is it well demonstrated that way?*

Comment: Certainly the right track. Maybe include explicit statement that $P(B) = \sum_i P(BA_i) = \sum_i P(B|A_i)P(A_i).$ (Law of Total Probability.) And fix typo in the numerator in the Question.

Comment: Quibble: Replaced `/` for 'given' by `|` throughout. Might check to see if I got them all. Also, fixed numerator.

Comment: I want to enlarge the size of the formulas in points 1, 2, 4 and 6 without using '$$'. You know how to do it?

Comment: @CarlosFrostte try `\displaystyle`